# is it possible to make an on(consolelog event? it would do something every time text is logged to console

Tags: javascript, node.js

This feature would do something every time text is logged to the node.js console.
Here's a somewhat of example of how I think it should look like:

`on('console', msg => {console.log("text was logged! " + msg)})`

Regular node.js

Comment: `console.log = (...args) => { /* whatever you like */ }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console methods don't emit events, but the console object and its methods can be overwritten, so you could redefine it yourself: `console.log = (...args) => { process.stdout.write('logged: ' + args.join(' ')) }`, or wrap it in a Proxy.

Comment: I have over 500 console.log() functions in my project. I was looking for more of a different way to do it all in one instead of putting it in each of them. Any ideas?

Comment: Could I ask what your actual intention is? Do you need to track emitted events, or is it that you want to change the log output? Logger libraries like Pino and Winston are a much more maintainable way to do the latter.

Comment: I'm looking to send everything logged to the console to my http server.

Comment: A logging module is the way to go, then. Check out the two I mentioned, they're pretty popular.

Comment: @NodeRanger - That idea is exactly what Zac is suggesting here.  Replace `console.log()` with your own version that does whatever you want to do.  But, if you're sending log info to your own server, I'd just use one of the prebuilt packages like Winston that has lots of useful features for that rather than build it all yourself.

Comment: @NodeRanger - In this answer, it is a function that they assigned to `console.log()` as a replacement.  It's an arrow function.